# When I start my sonarqube it's running but after 1 min its automatically get disconnected

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, devops, sonarqube-scan

When I start my sonarqube it's running but after 1 min its automatically get disconnected.
you can see my logs below:

```
root@ip-10-0-1-234:~# /opt/sonar/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
Starting SonarQube...
Started SonarQube.

ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-234:~$ /opt/sonar/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh status
Password: 
SonarQube is running (12854).

root@ip-10-0-1-234:~# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11316/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      629/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1162/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9142/postgres       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13486/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11316/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1162/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          :::*                    LISTEN      13519/java   

root@ip-10-0-1-234:~# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11316/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      629/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1162/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9142/postgres       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13486/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11316/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1162/sshd           

root@ip-10-0-1-234:~# /opt/sonar/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh status
SonarQube is not running.
```

sonar.log

```
INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up 
2020.05.21 14:23:55 INFO app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonar/sonarqube-$ 
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped 
2020.05.21 14:23:59 WARN app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143 
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped 
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped 
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

web.logs (incomplete)

```
    p//io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62) 
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:765) 
app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:413) 
app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909) 
java.base@11.0.7/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000 
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process
```

Comment: Share the logs, web.log, sonar.log

Comment: @HumayunM

sonar.log

 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2020.05.21 14:23:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonar/sonarqube-$
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped
2020.05.21 14:23:59 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped`

Comment: @HumayunM

web.logs

p//io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
 app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:765)
 app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:413)
 app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
 java.base@11.0.7/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2020.05.21 14:23:59 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process`

Comment: Hi @NikhilDusane, if we ask you on stackoverflow for your logs or additional information, we want to enrich your question, hence that it would be highly appreciated, if you could edit your question and add them there. Additionally you should properly format them with the editor. It makes it easier to help you, eg. identation of codes etc.

Comment: your logs also suggest you have an issue in your web.logs, please add more logoutput to your question